# Error al hacer una consulta en PHP para evitar la inyección SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una inserción en PHP y MySQL. Este es el código:

```
public static function Conectar()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BD;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    //Filtrando posibles errores de conexión.
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $pdo;
}
```

---

```
(isset($_POST['a']))?  $a = $_POST['a']: $a ="";
(isset($_POST['b']))?  $b = $_POST['b']: $b ="";
(isset($_POST['c']))?  $c = $_POST['c']: $c ="";


include("database.php");
$pdo = Database::Conectar();
try{
        //Sentencia SQL.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO respuesta (a,b,c)
                VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql);  
        $pdo->bindParam(1, $a, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $pdo->bindParam(2, $b, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $pdo->bindParam(3, $c, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $pdo->execute();

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\guardar.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\guardar.php on line 15

Y la linea a la que afecta es esta:
    $pdo->bindParam(1, $a, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);

La verdad no entiendo el porque me sale este error.

Comment: todo los parametros son `string`?

Comment: Si.  Los tres parámetros lo son

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta esto

```
include("database.php");
$pdo = Database::Conectar();
try{
        //Sentencia SQL.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO respuesta (a,b,c)
                VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $a, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $b, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $c, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

El método bindParam () está dentro de la clase PDOStatement, no de la clase PDO.